# How can I use array values in WHERE clauses?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to figure out how to use a array variable with a where clause.

when I echo $deader, I get 23,25,43,56,31,24,64,34,ect.. these are id numbers i want Updated

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET dead='DEAD' WHERE userID ='(".$deader.")' ");
```

The Array`$deader` has multiple values of id numbers, it only works and updates the first id# in the $deader Array.

I'm reading that Implode is what I need, but don't know how to get it into a functional format.

Comment: check WHERE...IN in mysql manuals.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the SQL you're generating and running it straight in the database? You should also look at moving away from `mysql_*` functions, as they're being deprecated.

Comment: Assuming that `$deader` is an array, you can `implode()` the array using `,` as the separator and use the `IN` clause.

Comment: Also possible: `FIELD_IN_SET()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MYSQL using an array in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 4):

Use `WHERE ... IN`

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET dead='DEAD' WHERE userID IN (".$deader.")");
```

Where $deader is in comma separated format. (for example: `$deader = '143, 554, 32'`)

If it is an array you can use `$deader = implode(',', $deader);` to make it comma separated.

---

**Note**:
 Please stop using mysql_* functions for new code. The functions aren't maintained anymore and the community has begun the deprecation process. See here for more info about converting this to PDO: [How do I convert a dynamically constructed ext/mysql query to a PDO prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327363/how-do-i-convert-a-dynamically-constructed-ext-mysql-query-to-a-pdo-prepared-sta/12327364#12327364) (thanks to PeeHaa)

Comment: If you're going to mention PDO, please use placeholders like [Mike Brant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1529853/mike-brant)'s answer did. Including things like `$deader` in the query is reckless and shouldn't be considered a valid answer.

Comment: @tadman That isn't an example of PDO, but the link he provided contains information about converting the old mysql_ to PDO as stated.

Comment: @tadman It would require some extra string work to get it done with `WHERE .. IN` statements in PDO. Here's an example how to do it: [PDO with “WHERE… IN” queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2373756/612202). You're free to edit :)

Comment: One extra line of code is a small price to pay. That link is a great example.

Answer (score 1):

If `$deader` is some sort of string of values, you will need to use MySQL `IN()` condition. Like this

```
UPDATE users SET dead = 'DEAD" WHERE userID IN ('?', '?', '?')
```

Where `?` are your values. If userID as an INTEGER field, you can omit the single quotes around the values, if it is a string field, they would be required.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the IN keyword in SQL.

```
UPDATE users set dead='DEAD' where userID in (100,101,102)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using MySQLi instead of mysql_*

```
require_once('.dbase'); //contains db constants DB_NAME, DB_USER etc
//using PHP built in connection class mysqli

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_UNAME,DB_UPWORD,DB_NAME);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
    $err = urlencode("Failed to open database connection: ".$mysqli->connect_error);
    header("Location: error.php?err=$err");
exit();
    }
$deader=implode(',',$deader); //assumes array, sting "143,554,32"
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET dead='DEAD' WHERE userID IN (?)"){
    //bind variable to statement object
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$deader) //var type[string],var to bind
    //execute query
    $stmt->execute();
    //feedback
    $rowsAffected = $stmt->affected_rows(); //update doesn't return a result set.
    //close statement object
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

You guys are hammering on Rickos for using mysql_* but not explaining how to do it otherwise,  my point was simply showing how to use mysqli.  A prepared statement isn't necessary, but since you marked my comment down (peehaa) for not showing it as a prepared statement, here it is edited as a prepared statement. And it does answer his questions.

Comment: mysqli isn't a silver bullet. I.e. it's not like I add an `i` and it is good. The statement should be changed to a prepared statement to be any safer than what OP currently has. And besides this doesn't answer OP.