# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Heres my code to connect to the database

```
function createConnection($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD){

    $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=****', $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);

}
```

and below and is the code for a function being called

```
function checkIfUserExists($dbc, $username, $table){

    global $dbc;

    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt = bindParam(1, $table);
    $stmt = bindParam(2, $username);
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

below is the code i use to call them

```
$connect = new databaseOperations;
$connect->createConnection($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
$connect->checkIfUserExists($dbc, login, Username);
```

my question is why am i getting the call to a member function prepare() on a non-object error when the page loads?

Comment: aiaiai, working with globals in OO code...

Comment: I could be wrong, but creating $dbc within a function, it isn't known outside of this function, right?

Comment: In addition to @WouterJ's answer, remember that PDOs bind data variables only. I.e. you can bind ? to username, but you cannot bind a table name. If you have a variable $table, you should include it in the query via string manipulations. But make sure to sanitize it if it comes from the user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405392/pdo-bindparam-issue/13406590#13406590

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 3):

You get that because the `$dbc` you pass to the `checkIfUserExists` method is not available in the global scope, only in the scope where it is created (in this case, the scope of `createConnection`).

The solution is simple: **Never ever use globals in your code** and the last code where you should use globals is in OOP code.

Use something like this:

```
class DatabaseOperations
{
    private $dbc;

    public function createConnection(...)
    {
        $this->dbc = new PDO(...);
    }

    public function checkIfUserExists(...)
    {
        $this->dbc->prepare(...);
        // ...
    }
}

$db = new DatabaseOperations();
$db->createConnection(...);
$db->checkIfUserExists(...);
```

Or return the `$dbc` variabele in the `createConnection` function and pass that to the other functions.

> **Important side note:** This is surely not the way you should use classes. Read something about OOP and program like that. In that case, you usually have a method on the `User` (Active Record) or `UserMapper` (DataMapper) object to check if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createConnection($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD){

    $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=****', $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    return $dbc; // <---- add this...

}

function checkIfUserExists($dbc, $username, $table){

// ---> no need to use global, because you pass $dbc as an argument
```

calling...

```
$dbc = $connect->createConnection($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: please note that you also need to save the return value in a var called `$dbc`

Comment: yes, of course, I clarified it in my answer.